# How to show Xelatex log in shell when converting latex to PDF from shell?

Tags: xetex, performance, logging

This is my first question here. Basically I'm a programmer. I've been working with a project where we are using xelatex to convert latex to PDF. We are using Ubuntu 18 server environment and installed tex-live full package.

Now the problem is when we are trying to convert a latex file to pdf using shell command its not showing any progress or any logs. No nothing. So far we get from the shell output is **"Entering extended mode"**.

[image: Shell Output]

We find the log in the directory where the pdf file is generated but we really need the logs in the shell. Is there any way I can do so?

Here is the command we are using to convert latex to pdf:

```
/usr/bin/xelatex --no-shell-escape --interaction=batchmode  filename.tex
```

Is there any other command I've to add to this command above to log in the console?

Please help me out.

The problem is we are converting **programmatically generated latex file which contains 20,000 (Twenty Thousand) pages** after pdf conversion. The problem is, at our bench mark we found out that **conversion time takes around 0.593285 second per page**. So for a **20,000 page it will take around 3.3hours** which is huge. Usually shell die after 10minutes of inactivity mean if nothing is outputting in log for more than 10min, it will die. So the process dies (but not the conversion), and so the program which is running the shell. I've been looking for how to keep alive shell for longer, but if we can put logs in the shell then it will be great as the logs will keep the shell active.

Also is there any way I can boost up the conversion time? I've to use xelatex as I've unicode characters in there. Also I've images in there too. The page size is **A3paper**.

Any help  is appreciated.

**My server configuration**

```
Intel xeon 1230 (3.2GHz)
4 cores, 8 threads
RAM: 32GB
OS: Ubuntu 18

XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Compiled with ICU version 60.2; using 60.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.8.1; using 2.8.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.11; using 1.3.11
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 1.7.2; using 1.7.2
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.12.6; using 2.12.6
```

Comment: don't use batchmode but for example scrollmode.

Comment: So you are suggesting to use scrollmode rather than batchmode? So far I heard that batchmode is faster.

Comment: Hay, that is great advice. Thanks dear a lot. I hope this could be my solve. Let me check.

Comment: it is only faster because it avoids writing to the terminal...

Comment: but can't you run the batchmode version under nohup or similar so it is not connected to the terminal session? It seems odd that you need to write to an interactive terminal on a server

Comment: Off topic: what kind of project produces 20K A3 pages? Tables? Posters? Plots?

Comment: research data dear.